# How can I render 2d images from a lot of camera angles from a 3d model in blender

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 2d

I am planning on obtaining different images from various camera angles of a 3d model. So I need images of an object from different camera perspectives, for example, like how would an object look when camera is placed at different angles and rotated circularly 360 degrees around a particular axis of the object. Can I do do that in Blender or is there a script available for this kind of work ? Please let me know.

Comment: Can you make your question more understandable?

Comment: Sure, I have a 3d model of a drone, and I am planning on getting images of how the drone looks from different angles. So I am looking at any blender script that can do that.

Comment: this addon (included with 2.79) could help https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/TurnaroundCamera/

Comment: Yes, this is somewhat similar to what I was looking at, can you suggest any methods through which I can render image frames of the entire view, or render it to an animation or video atleast ? Please let me know

Comment: Do you mean that you want the camera to be animated orbiting around the object? Please update you question with a clearified explanation and preferably an example.

Comment: I edited my question, I could make the object turn around right now, but I am unable to render pictures of it.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82240/29586